# Women's Blood Siphoned Out to Feed Invading Aliens

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

The film is in color and is probably from the late 1970s or the early 1980s. I could not see the ff. scene in Battle Beyond the Stars or Star Crash.

A woman is strapped on to a vertical plane, where another with tiny needles attached to transparent tubes is moved to her. Blood is slowly siphoned from her body. There is a brief close up showing her nipple as one of the tubes is attached to her breast.

I'm not sure, but I think the aliens (who are humanoids) need blood to stay alive, and plan to invade earth.

Comment: Was it a remake (There were a couple at least) of "Not of this Earth?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is [L'umanoide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080058/). I also was looking for this movie for a long time and identified it by pure chance, I came upon [this article in io9.com](http://io9.com/5909094/some-of-the-cheesiest-movie-moments-of-all-time/gallery/1?tag=retro-future):

> It also has some of the best Darth Vader dialog ever, a robot dog named Robodog, a psychic Jedi-child, and an evil queen who has to absorb the juices of one topless young fashion model every day to stay young

Answer (score 2):

Could it be 1985's *Evils of the Night*? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evils_of_the_Night):

> Evils of the Night is a 1985 low-budget science fiction/"porno horror"
>   film starring Aldo Ray, Neville Brand, Tina Louise, John Carradine,
>   and Julie Newmar.
>
> Vampire aliens Dr. Kozmar (Carradine), Dr. Zarma (Newmar) and Cora
>   (Louise) recruit two dim-witted mechanics (Ray and Brand) to abduct
>   teenagers living in a college town and bring them to a rural hospital.
>   There, the aliens drain them of their blood, which they need to stay
>   young.

[image]

Comment: great poster, especially the Millennium Falcon rip-off, LOL

Comment: @ShaneFinneran Wait till you see the green laser beams shooting out of it - the movie clips I found were pretty amusing

Comment: It's The Humanoid, but thanks for sharing this movie. I will look for that, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scene similar (ish) to this in Dark Angel?

The alien kills a girl with a massive drug overdose and then drains a fluid from her to use as a drug.

It has Dolph Lundgrun in it.

Comment: It was something like Starship Invasions (1977), but I could not see any scene like it in this movie.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a long-shot, but could it be [Life Force.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeforce_%28film%29)

I say this as it is just within your timescale and involves alien vampires, which links to the symphonic of blood. I saw this years ago, so do not know if the scene you describe is in the film or not. The title just came to my mind while reading your description.

Comment: I saw Lifeforce but could not find the scene in it. Also, I think what was siphoned off in that movie was energy from living beings.