Film about serial killer who kidnaps girl and kills her by throwing her into a machine, then drinks her blood
As title says, this film was about serial killer who kidnaps a girl and kills her by throwing her into a machine and then drinks her blood. After throwing the girl inside the machine, the blood comes out from a tube and the killer was drinking it.
First the serial killer goes to girl's house (according to what I he may have been repairing something in the house). The killer's house did not contain any windows. At one point a thief enters the house but can't then find a way out. The killer finds the thief and put him into the machine.
I watched this English-language live-action film after 2007 and I think it was made between 2000 and 2007.

Maybe one of the answers to this?  http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/womens-blood-siphoned-out-to-feed-invading-aliens

This sounds like The Mangler Reborn from 2005, the second low-budget sequel to The Mangler.

The movie takes place after the events in the first film and follows Hadley (Weston Blakesley), a repairman that purchases the possessed machine from the first movie and becomes obsessed with the machine. Hadley awakens the machine with his blood and after being "eaten" by it, is forced to feed it new blood to stop his corpse from rotting.

He feeds people into the machine in his basement and then drinks their blood. In the course of the film, he does it to a woman and then to a burglar who enters his house. Here's the trailer [Warning: Gory]:



